# Clear Workbox's Registry constant

Tags: workbox

In workbox, Listing of workflow items can be customized using **Registry.SetString("/Current_User/Workflow/FilterOption")**. but how to clear this filteroption & rollback to default. currently while testing i'm using powershell console or codebehind to do this everytime but wondering whether it can be doable through clearing cache in 'admin/cache.aspx'. Any input on this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `Registry.SetString(key,value)` or any other `Registry.Set*` you're setting in fact this value on user profile:

```
Sitecore.Context.User.Profile[key] = value;
```

Clearing the cache will not help you here. Even if you clear the value in cache, it will still be set on the profile and loaded from there if needed.

---

**EDIT**

I've written a blog post describing how you can work with Sitecore Registry and with simple [Sitecore Registry Editor](https://www.skillcore.net/sitecore/sitecore-registry-editor) application.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i'm currently using powershell console to do this like [Sitecore.Web.UI.HtmlControls.Registry]::SetString("/Current_User/Workflow/TemplateFilter",'')   and finding appropriate way to clear them while showing demo to clients :)

Comment: So you're not clearing the cache. You're clearing the registry value using code.

Comment: yes, believing clearing cache can clear the value & rollback to default entry. but this didnt workout. so using console to reset value :(

Comment: Cache is only another layer for caching so you don't need to get the value from the profile itself. You can add simple aspx page which will contains buttons for clearing what you need if you want to use something less hardcore than ps scripts ;)